# Login Screen not working

Tags: login, login-screen

After being inactive for a while I try to login and this happens. No matter what key I press, I don't get to enter username/password. The only thing I can press is the top right corner and that's what I get (screenshot).
The only solution is restarting the computer by pressing the power button for a few seconds and then turning it on again.
I have the latest version of Ubuntu (19.04).

[image]

Comment: what if you click and drag your mouse upwards from the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Nothing happens